# Changing navigationController.delegate causes to bad access

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new t iOS dev.

I've a view pushed in navigationController, let say it is the 3rd pushed view. 
In that view I set `self.navigationController.delegate = self;`. I've changed delegate because I need to handle case when user goes to previous view i.e. pops from current view.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([[viewController class] isEqual:[MainViewController class]]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It works OK, but when I pop the current view and press navigation back button again (i.e. switching to first pushed view) I'm getting bad access error.

So what I'm missing ? 
What is the correct way to handle navigation back button press ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because navigation controller sends a message to popped and deallocated view controller, you have to set the delegate each time you do the popping and pushing. Also add `self.navigationController.delegate = nil;` to dealloc method of your viewController.

Comment: actually setting delegate to nil in dealloc did not help... 
In my case, the 3rd view implements UINavigationControllerDelegate the others do not ? So where do I need to set delegate to self, in all views ?

Comment: If I got you correctly delegate should be set to nil in the view where if was set to self every time when your going to push or pop. 
At least I've done so and it seems to work ... Please confirm

Comment: Well of course it has to be set for each view controller. Confirm. The reason why you should set delegate to nil, is to avoid "dangling" pointers (pointers to deallocated memory). The EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually happens when you send a message to deallocated object and since your Navigation controller's delegate was a deallocated object you've been getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Place below in the Viewcontroller in which you assigning self.navigationController.delegate = self

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated
{  
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   if ([self isMovingFromParentViewController])
   {
      if (self.navigationController.delegate == self)
      {
           self.navigationController.delegate = nil;
      }
   }
}
```